# show years between begin and end

Tags: python, datetime, plone

How can I count and show all years between an given Beginn and a given End?

My Example:

```
for item in folderContents:
    Beginn = item.Beginn.strftime('%Y')
    Ende = item.Ende.strftime('%Y')
    try:
        Beginn = Beginn
        while Beginn <= Ende:
            Beginn = Beginn + 1
            print Beginn
    except:
        pass
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for item in folderContents:
    Beginn = int(item.Beginn.strftime('%Y'))
    Ende = int(item.Ende.strftime('%Y'))

    for year in range(Beginn, Ende + 1):
        print year
```